# How to deploy the Azure API Management to a different environment

Tags: .net, azure, azure-api-management

How can I deploy the Azure API Management to a different environment? We have the development version of APIM now, and we are moving to test. So in order to create an apim in test environment, what is the process (other than manual)?

Comment: Would Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates work for your case or is this what you refer to as manual?

Comment: 1.Could you please supply more info about what you have done? 2. Could you please explan more about `development version` or `test envrionment` ?

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET I dont see any of the settings from my API management getting exported into the ARM zip. APIs with inbound etc. how can this replace the Git way suggested earlier?

Answer (score 1):

ARM templates are being rolled out as we speak, so within a week that should be available on all instances.

the workflow would be:

1. Export ARM template of complete development environment
2. Remove items not yet ready for the staging environment
3. Deploy this template on the staging environment

Maybe there will be better ways/tips/tricks as soon as everyone works more with the ARM template feature.

Our current (involving manual steps) way of deploying is this:

1. Export GIT repositories(pull) of dev and staging
2. Use a 2 way (or 3 way) merge tool to transfer the right items to staging
3. Push the changes to staging

We created this workflow because ARM templates were not available

Comment: I tried cloning the Git repository and it gives me load of files with everything i can imagine needed for re deploying. I also did the export ARM and downloaded the zip packge. It does not seem to contain any of the API management mapping, inbound rules, policies etc. Is the ARM really a replacement?

Comment: My team is also doing something similar to Erik's manual step workflow which is a total pain and very error prone.  This thread is two years old now and I still don't see an actual solution for copying APIM between environments.